# Sonarqube: error parse on c++ file

Tags: c++, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am using sonar-qube 4.5.4 with C++ commercial plugin the latest version.

For visual c++ plugin the analysis is failing (the totalLineOfCode of some source files is 0) because  parsing error on some cpp files.

Here is an example of the error raised:

```
Parse error in file C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\metrics.artifacts_Error\dfinstaller\sources\PasswordRecovery\AboutDlg.h at line 7: 

7:  class CAboutDlg : public CDialogImpl < CAboutDlg >
                            ^
8:  {
9:  public :
10:  enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX } ;
12:  BEGIN_MSG_MAP ( CAboutDlg )
13:  MESSAGE_HANDLER ( WM_INITDIALOG , OnInitDialog )
14:  COMMAND_ID_HANDLER ( IDOK , OnCloseCmd )
```

The file content in question :

```
// aboutdlg.h : interface of the CAboutDlg class
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#pragma once

class CAboutDlg : public CDialogImpl<CAboutDlg>
{
public:
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CAboutDlg)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_INITDIALOG, OnInitDialog)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(IDOK, OnCloseCmd)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(IDCANCEL, OnCloseCmd)
    END_MSG_MAP()


// Handler prototypes (uncomment arguments if needed):
//  LRESULT MessageHandler(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
//  LRESULT CommandHandler(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
//  LRESULT NotifyHandler(int /*idCtrl*/, LPNMHDR /*pnmh*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
};
```

Any help for solving the parsing problem is very appreciated.

Comment: What's the question? Is this the whole error message?

Comment: Contact support for help with commercial plugins

Comment: @SimonKraemer the problem is the parsing error which causing the totalLinesOfCode to be 1 although the file has more than one line.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam okay because in the support page there this: Go to StackOverflow for questions like:
How do I… ?
I got this error, why ?